# Do a check on Backbone.History

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I need to perform a check on Backbone.History.

I have setup a modal box to work with a direct URL. When this is accessed from a list within the application, and then the closed button is clicked, I use:

```
window.history.back();
```

Yet, if the model box is accessed by a direct link, when the close button is clicked, I need to use:

```
router.navigate("item/"+id, true);
```

Is it possible to check if Backbone.History contains URL fragments?

Comment: Why don't you just use `router.navigate("item/"+id, true)` for both cases? Are you not going to the same place? In other words, once you start using a router, why mess with `window.history`

Comment: The behavior of the application is unexpected when invoking the modal by pressing the back button, ex. someone clicks an item from the list, closes the list, clicks another item, clicks the back button twice, they will return to the open model rather than, ideally, the previous page.

Comment: I'd have to see an example of what you're describing -- when I start to really think about it, a modal dialog is just that -- modal.  You should never be able to see it without specifically requesting it (i.e. hitting back shouldn't re-present a modal dialog.) Why would you want them to go back to modal without specifically re-triggering it?

Comment: The issue isn't wanting to go back to the active modal, yet to both allow people to directly access the model from an external link and select from a list, and then adjust the 'close' button to function differently based on how the model was invoked.